# Difference between ! and nil check on Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, comparison, null

I'm teaching myself Objective-C 2.0.

I see from various code samples, the following two approaches to test if an object has been initialised. If that's not exactly what these tests do, please correct me.

Can you please explain the difference between the following:

```
if (!myObject)
```

and

```
if (myObject == nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All objects are set to nil in the alloc method (or to zero for instance variables). Both of your cases checks if the object is equal to nil (is not initialized) and both will work. They are equivalent to each other. It is a matter of taste which one you prefer. Personally I tend to use

```
if (!myObject)
```

because it is my *personal* preference. Hope it helps!